# running system command having output filename as argument in JAVA

Tags: java, system.io.file

```
String fileName = javaoutput.out            
String target = "Mltexp -owprj xyz -output abc.out"

Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(target); 

InputStream i = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(i);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr); 

try (FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName)) { // for appending use (f,true)
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    while((br.readLine()) != null){   
        fw.write(br.readLine());
        // You can also use append.
    }    
    bw.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Problem writingw riting the file");
}
```

I need to run a system command which is having the argument "-output" for specifying output filename. My code is creating a javaoutput.out file displaying error  "not able to open output file for writing".

I tried   system command  "Mltexp -owprj xyz -output /dev/stdout" also. Again javaoutput.out file display same error  "not able to open output file for writing"

Comment: Have you tried to execute that system command with the same parameter in command line?

Comment: Can you execute the command successfully with any `-output` argument?

Comment: You can't create `/dev/stdout` unless it already exists, and I wouldn't expect it to. On Linux you can write to `/proc/self/fd/1` which is std out.

Comment: System command with the same parameter is executing successful in command line

Comment: @HeikkiMäenpää 
 
System command with the same parameter .i.e -output argument  is executing successful in command line

Comment: @Alex System command with the same parameter is executing successful in command line

Comment: @PeterLawrey Actually i need to write to a output file. In command line the  -ouput parameter value set to "/dev/stdout" do  display the result on screen. But when the same command is run using java, error again is cannot open file for writing.